# sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade 7 not upgraded

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

`sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`

```
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
7 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done'

The following packages have been kept back:

xorg xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-void xserver-xorg-video-dummy

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded
```

When i open `update-manager` the following comes up:

```
You don't have the required privileges to perform this action.
```

I press "Ok", this comes up:

```
the software on this computer is up to date.
However, Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS is now available (you have 16.04)
```

i press Upgrade.
Nothing happenes.

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

`lsb-release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Using A Chromebook R13 with crouton installed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as your question does not fit any of our guidelines

Comment: oh, okay will do.

Comment: I think this should be posted instead at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). See their help page for [what's on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by editing "sources.list"

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

All updates are up to date

thanks for the help

Comment: Hi, Im having the same problem. How did you actually edit it?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Ubuntu 16.04/17.10 to Ubuntu 18.04 with the Graphical Update Manager

First of all, fire up a terminal window and run the following command to update existing software packages.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

After upgrade run this command

```
update-manager
```

After checking for updates, the update manager will tell you that Ubuntu 18.04 is now available. Click the Upgrade button.

That all you need.